# How to use SwiftMessage cocoapod into my application using Swift?

Tags: ios, swift

In my scenario, I am trying to integrate card popup top side like a toast message into my app. So, I decided to integrate `SwiftMeesage` cocoa pod into my application. I didn’t get a proper step by step procedure for integration. Below steps I am done but further more I need clarification.

https://github.com/SwiftKickMobile/SwiftMessages

1. Installed `pod 'SwiftMessages`
2. Created `CardView.xib`
3. CardView.xib class and module What I need to give?

How to call this xib from multiple viewcontroller. I am enabling button so where I need to handle button action. As per the repository document info class and module information not gave properly. Please provide steps to integrate this module.

**Custom Class UIView**

```
guard let view = Bundle.main.loadNibNamed("ToastView.", owner: nil, options: nil)?.first as? ToastView else { return }
var config = SwiftMessages.defaultConfig
config.presentationContext = .window(windowLevel: UIWindow.Level.statusBar)
config.duration = SwiftMessages.Duration.seconds(seconds: 5) // show in 5 seconds for example
SwiftMessages.show(config: config, view: view)
```

Answer (score 2):

I would suggest you using a custom view instead of the default `CardView` then you can do more customizations.

The code could be like this:

```
guard let view = Bundle.main.loadNibNamed("YourCustomView.", owner: nil, options: nil)?.first as? YourCustomView.  else { return }
var config = SwiftMessages.defaultConfig
config.presentationContext = .window(windowLevel: UIWindow.Level.statusBar)
config.duration = SwiftMessages.Duration.seconds(seconds: 5) // show in 5 seconds for example 
SwiftMessages.show(config: config, view: view)
```

If you dont want to use custom view

```
let view = MessageView.viewFromNib(layout: .cardView)
// Customize icon, title, body... here
SwiftMessages.show(config: config, view: view)
```

Comment: how to call this from each view controller?

Comment: Copy and wrap above lines of code into a helper class or something like that, then use it anywhere you want to show the message bar.

Comment: I am getting error `Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'NSInternalInconsistencyException', reason: 'Could not load NIB in bundle: 'NSBundle` for customview

Comment: Yes, above code is a sample, you need to create your own custom view and load it from bundle. Or you can test by create an instance of UIView then pass it to the function `SwiftMessages.show(config: config, view: view)`

Comment: I created custom .xib and for that custom UIView class. Now, How I need to use it into MainViewController ?

Comment: You just need to make sure you get a valid `view` from this 
`guard let view = Bundle.main.loadNibNamed("YourCustomView.", owner: nil, options: nil)?.first as? YourCustomView.  else { return }` 
Then copy my above lines of code to show it.

Comment: yes its all correct I create `toastView.xib` and `toastView.swift` now how to call it with SwiftMessage?

Comment: Please read and follow my guidance above, you just need to replace the my view by your view then it works

Comment: @jacobs I updated my question. Its not calling buddy

Comment: Did you get a valid view? Or it is nil?

Comment: getting crash `Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'NSInternalInconsistencyException', reason: 'Could not load NIB in bundle: 'NSBundle`

Comment: So the problem is that you cannot get the instance of your view from xib file, pls double check that mate